# Rails: Active record query conditions only work if stated as sql -- using Globalize gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, globalize

Not sure if there is a fix for this that you know of, but when using the the globalize gem

```
class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base

  translates :name
  # other stuff ... 

end
```

if I write an active record query as standard, it products an empty set.

-- Generically

```
Model.where(attribute: "Value")
```

doesn't work, where

```
Model.where('attribute = ?', 'Value')
```

does work.

--- A real world example from the console on my Menu model:

```
2.3.0 (main):0 > Menu.where(name: "Lunch Boxes")
=> []
2.3.0 (main):0 > Menu.where('name = ?', "Lunch Boxes")
=> [#<Menu:0x007fbab6dc6838 id: 12, restaurant_id: 15, name: "Lunch Boxes", created_at: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 16:07:20 EDT -04:00, updated_at: Thu, 10 Aug 2017 14:48:38 EDT -04:00>]
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Just for good measure

Rails 4.2.6
Ruby  2.3.0

Comment: I don't know what globalize is doing behind your back but comparing `Model.where(attribute: "Value").to_sql` and `Model.where('attribute = ?', 'Value').to_sql` might be enlightening. Looking at the raw table data (i.e. without any ActiveRecord noise in the way) might also be enlightening.

Comment: mu you are a genius.  Bleh.  With a quick view at your suggestion of to_sql, it became clear, if a translation is missing in the translation table, the model (with the attribute that needs translating during lookup) returns nil - so the collection is empty. Foiled my mine own app (which is functioning-as-designed apparently).  Thanks

Comment: Might be worthwhile converting that comment into an answer. All the magic can be very puzzling when things don't "just work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @mu-is-too-short -- no idea how long it would have taken to figure that out on my own.

The trick to figuring out what was happening was to convert to two commands I was comparing to sql so I could see exactly what was being attempted.

```
Menu.where(name: "Lunch Boxes").to_sql
Menu.where('name = ?', "Lunch Boxes").to_sql
```

These produced, respectively:

```
=> "SELECT \"menus\".* FROM \"menus\" WHERE (name = 'Lunch Boxes')"
```

and

```
=> "SELECT \"menus\".* FROM \"menus\" INNER JOIN \"menu_translations\" 
  ON \"menu_translations\".\"menu_id\" = \"menus\".\"id\" WHERE 
  \"menu_translations\".\"name\" = 'Lunch Boxes' AND 
  \"menu_translations\".\"locale\" = 'fr'"
```

So then I ran the query directly in the psql console, and came back with an empty set.  Because it was joining on the menu_translations table, made possible by using the model helper that comes with the Globalize gem, ie:

```
 translates :name
```

SO then I checked the translation table, and found that the term "Lunch Boxes" didn't exist with any translation, and because the the attribute `name` is globalized, it requires a translation.

Added the translation, problem solved.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

It's all right. You are trying to get this data from class, and rails waiting for filter for special characters.

More info - [SQL Injection: 7.2.4 Countermeasures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

Comment: Huh?  You might have misunderstood.  The section of doc you pointed me  to read says "OR you can pass a hash for the same result" -- I'm simply trying to pass the hash, and getting an empty result, instead of the record(s) I get by using the SQL fragment.  Both are valid statements, why doesn't the hash version work?  That's my question.

Comment: @trh Looks like one can never have enough security things :)
But i understood your point. You are tried this on rails v.5+?

Comment: No, I'm stuck in rails 4 for this app.  Boooooooooooooooooooo.

Comment: @trh accept my condolences. I tried this on 5.1.4, both query works fine. Well, I guess there's our answer.